# Параллельное умножение матрицы на вектор для решения СЛАУ в Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно попробовать ускорить процесс решения СЛАУ. У меня есть обратная матрица A[NxN] и вектор B[N] мне нужно перемножить их для получения решения. Я хочу разделить матрицу А по столбцам и параллельно перемножить на элементы матрицы B, а потом сложить результат умножений. Могу ли я как то разделить A по столбам и что можно использовать для параллельного решения

Comment: Для параллельных вычислений используйте отдельные потоки. Что бы разделить по столбцам - проходитесь вложенным циклом for (или while)

Comment: Для этого есть numpy